# Add ComboBox to a project in pure ActionScript 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, combobox, flashdevelop

I'm trying to use a `ComboBox` control in an ActionScript 3.0 Project I've been tasked with making modifications to. I know I need to do

```
import fl.controls.ComboBox;
```

Now, the problem is that if I do this within the (unfamiliar) environment of FlashDevelop, I get an error. My understanding is that adding a control is a matter of feeing FlashDevelop the correct classpath, which I think I've done. Some other websites seem to indicate that if I add the control to my library this problem goes away because the act of putting it in the library links the required resources.

So, how can I do the equivalent of adding to an .FLA library within FlashDevelop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to link them into your class path. The class path changed a while back not sure what it is now. It is just like adding any other lib to your class path.

Here is a topic about it.

http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=4344

Edit: Skip the part where they are saying publish a swf.

Comment: Turns out adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS4\Common\Configuration\Component Source\ActionScript 3.0\User Interface` to my `CLASSPATH` ended up working. *BUT* the advice to put the components into a .FLA and publish a SWC also worked as an alternative. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Yea just pushing a few things into a published SWC works fine it just always seemed icky to me heh. Glad it worked.